# Proof check of harmonicity

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$open $u$ continuously differentiable twice  and for every $\phi \in C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ $$0= \int_{\Omega} \langle Du,D\phi\rangle$$

Then, integrating by parts I get $$0= \int_{\Omega}  \Delta u \cdot \phi$$  and by the fundamental lemma of calulus of variations and continuity of $u$ I should get $u$ is harmonic. Am I reasoning correctly?

Comment: Try \langle and \rangle instead of < and >

Comment: If $u$ is just Lipschitz continuous, why should $\Delta u$ make sense?

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine (if you want to be thorough, I'd add a line saying that since $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$, there are no boundary terms in the integration by parts).

Answer (score 0):

[I assume $u$ is atleast twice differentible to work with] You should use density argument.

Set of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ dense in $C^0(\Omega)$ in $L^2$ norm.

So there exists $\phi_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega) $, such that $\phi_n\to \Delta u$. So
$$0=\int \Delta u \phi_n\to \int |\Delta u|^2$$
This implies $u$ is harmonic. (Non negative function with integral zero)

Comment: Why shouldn't I just use the fundamental lemma of calculus of variations?

Comment: Your answer is actually not so useful in telling me what I should do without telling me why I cannot do in the way I listed above